# Upload File with zip laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, zip

I want to upload files(not zipped files) in the server but it should be zipped when it is uploaded. I studied Chumper/zipper package too but i am still not convinced. If any body can suggest me how can i do that, please help me. I am new in laravel 5.1

Comment: usually, compressing makes upload faster since there are large number of files in a project. Can you explain what's problem with uploading zipped files in your case ?

Comment: i want to upload a file which is not zipped( suppose .doc file) but it should be should be zipped when it is uploaded in server. So we should do process to zip file before uploading file.

Comment: Yes, If file is small or small number of files, you can upload with out zipping. In your case for single `.doc` file, you can upload without zipping.

for large  number of files to be uploaded, compressing is preferred. You can zip files and then extract on the server which will take less time and efficient as well

Comment: but my major concern is to automate that process of zipping so user don't have to zip before uploading. That process will take place in server side. Is that possible from Chumper/zipper package

Comment: I haven't used that package before, Anyone here might have some idea. Best of luck

Comment: thanks for your kind suggestion Sagar Gautam

Comment: You are from  Budanilkantha, Kathmandu 
Wow I'm at Sankhamul